# Doubleclick for bid manager CreateQuery stopped working

Tags: google-analytics-api

We've been using the following query for the CreateQuery API in Doubleclick for Bid Managers successfully for the past few months, but it has stopped working since yesterday with the error:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid Value",
"locationType": "other",
"location": "params.filter.value"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid Value"
}
}
```

This may make sense (there is no filter value defined in the query) but I'm confused as to why it has always worked. The commit history shows that the query request has not changed over time and results have been produced.

If I include the filter and add a value it produces the same error HTTP 400 error.

If I remove the filter (we don't actually want to filter out any data) it will error that "At least one of FILTER_PARTNER or FILTER_ADVERTISER must be set."

Understanding why it has stopped working would be interesting but I think the question would be: how can we create this query without having to define any filters?

```
"kind": "doubleclickbidmanager#query",
"queryId": 1122334455,
"metadata": {
"title": "abc",
"dataRange": "LAST_7_DAYS",
"format": "CSV",
"locale": "en"
},
"params": {
"type": "TYPE_GENERAL",
"groupBys": [
"FILTER_ADVERTISER"
,"FILTER_ADVERTISER_CURRENCY"
,"FILTER_ADVERTISER_TIMEZONE"
,"FILTER_INSERTION_ORDER"
],
"filters": [
{
"type": "FILTER_ADVERTISER",
}
],
"metrics": [
"METRIC_IMPRESSIONS"
]
},
"schedule": {
"frequency": "DAILY",
"nextRunMinuteOfDay": 120,
"nextRunTimezoneCode": "Europe/London"
},
"timezoneCode": "Europe/London"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar error occurred,
If you change the "filters" specification, you have successfully requested
```
"filters": [
{
"type": "FILTER_ADVERTISER",
}

↓

"filters": [
{
"type": "FILTER_PARTNER",
"value": "xxxxxx"
}
```

FILTER_ADVERTISERは扱うとどうしてもエラーが発生してしまうようです。

Comment: FILTER_ADVERTISER seems to cause an error by handling absolutely.